# how to give base address of 2d array to pointers

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose we have

```
int a[2][3] ;
int (*p)[3]=a; // is ok
int (*p)[3]=&a[0]; // is also ok
```

but why is

```
int (*p)[3]=a[0];
```

producing errors , although `a[0]` gives first array's address(as 2d arrays are array of array) and seems more 
okay than `&a[0]` which gives address of first element of first array still is ok but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Given the declaration

```
int a[2][3];
```

Then the following are true:

```
        Expression        Type            Decays To      Equivalent Value
        ----------        ----            ---------      ----------------
                 a        int [2][3]      int (*)[3]     &a[0]
                &a        int (*)[2][3]   n/a            n/a
                *a        int [3]         int *          a[0]
              a[i]        int [3]         int *          n/a
             &a[i]        int (*)[3]      n/a            n/a
             *a[i]        int             n/a            a[i][0]
           a[i][j]        int             n/a            n/a
```

Note that `a`, `&a`, `*a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` all yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array), but the types are different.

As you can see from the table above, the expression `a[0]` has type "3-element array of `int`"; since that expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `int`", which is not compatible with "pointer to *3-element array of* `int`", which is why `int (*p)[3] = a[0];` throws an error.

Comment: But how we check the type of expression like *a and &a[i] in case of 2d array like this

Comment: Plzz help me iam on this topic from 10 days

Answer (score 2):

Because `a[0]` is not a pointer type, but an `int[3]` type. A block of 3 integers which can be assigned to such, but not to a pointer.

Comment: No, `a` is an `int[2][3]` type.

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*p)[3]=a; // is OK
```

because `a` is of type `int (*)[3]` (pointer to an array of 3 `int`s), after decay to the first element which is also the type of `p`. Assignment is legal.

```
int (*p)[3]=&a[0]; // is also OK
```

because `&a[0]` is also of type `int (*)[3]` (address of the first row)

```
int (*p)[3]=a[0]; // is not OK
```

because `a[0]` is of type `int *` after decay to the first element of row `0`. Assignment of different pointer types is illegal.

Comment: Hey int(*p)[3] = a; is okay

Answer (score 0):

How a[0] can be of type int or int[3] as we have declared it a 2d array

Comment: `a[0]` is not of type `int`. It is of type `int[3]`, i.e, an array of `3` `int`s, which is converted to `int *`.